# FTDI library error on ARMv7

Tags: compilation, embedded-linux, armv7, ftdi

I have a router Asus RT-AC68R with 32GB memory pen mounted to /opt. On it is installed entware including all the tools to build programs natively on the platform ARMv7. Router use TomatoUSB firmware.

I wrote a program to support the module based on the chip FT245 connected via USB to the router. The program compiled on Linux x86_64 and it works correctly on a standard Linux PC. It was - of course - necessary installing library supplied by the manufacturer (FTDI). The manufacturer provides these libraries for various platforms, including the ARMv7 versions soft and hard float. On router I installed library hard float.
These libraries are [HERE](http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX.htm)

So I'm trying to compile the program, prior to the installation of the pen FTDI libraries, according to the documentation. Unfortunately, after starting the program an library error occurs.

Below the way I compile this program (named arco) and the result of running this program on my ARMv7 based router.

```
root@asus:/opt# gcc -Wl,-rpath=/opt/usr/local/lib -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/opt/lib/ld-linux.so.3 -L/opt/usr/local/lib -O2 -pipe -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a9 -fno-caller-saves -mfloat-abi=soft -l ftd2xx arco.c -o arco
root@asus:/opt# ./arco
./arco: error while loading shared libraries: /opt/usr/local/lib/libftd2xx.so: internal error
```

Additional information about my dev environment:

```
root@asus:/opt/FTDI# echo $PATH
/opt/bin:/opt/sbin:/opt/bin:/opt/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/root:/mmc/sbin:/mmc/bin:/mmc/usr/sbin:/mmc/usr/bin:/opt/sbin:/opt/bin:/opt/usr/sbin:/opt/usr/bin:
root@asus:/opt/FTDI# echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib:/opt/lib:/opt/usr/lib:/opt/include
root@asus:/opt/FTDI# opkg list-installed|grep gcc
gcc - 5.4.0-1
libgcc - 5.4.0-5
root@asus:/opt# uname -a
Linux asus 2.6.36.4brcmarm #5 SMP PREEMPT Tue Aug 16 22:49:47 CEST 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I am fairly new when it comes to platform ARMv7 but maybe there is something in compilation options I use:

```
-mfloat-abi=soft
```

a library installed is hard-float. I do not know if this could be the reason so expect council colleagues.
Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: Have you already checked if [libftdi](https://www.intra2net.com/en/developer/libftdi/) could be used instead of proprietary libftd2xx.so? This library is included in many Linux distros like Buildroot, OpenWRT(LEDE) etc.

Comment: Probably yes. But I have ready program in C, working properly on Linux x86_64 with proprietary libftd2xx.so. All I want is to recompile it on ARMv7 platform